# How can I remove stock date column from a data frame

Tags: pandas

Running the code in the link below gives the following output

```
Index(['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], dtype='object')
```

The code grab yahoo stock prices that show up like this in the data frame

```
    High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
2014-04-03  10.800  9.05    9.86    9.06    12004000.0  8.681220
2014-04-04  9.380   8.73    9.10    9.04    1844100.0   8.662056
2014-04-07  8.950   7.99    8.86    8.06    2562600.0   7.723028
2014-04-08  8.604   8.06    8.12    8.50    959500.0    8.144632
2014-04-09  8.660   8.20    8.47    8.44    981000.0    8.087140
```

How do I drop the date column so my training data does include the data that shows up as dtype='object'

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uEHKCntVS73b9WQvTxwTegpnbBtI4VNK?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is an index here so you have two options;

**1. Drop the index directly;**

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**2. Select column by type using [`.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)**

```
# 'Date' to column 
df = df.reset_index()

# select strings too
df = df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
```